# slicing from a different given position strings on a list

Tags: python

Im trying to build a function that slices strings in a list according to a given integer, but cant seem to figure out how.

```
my_list = ["GGCTATATAGCGCGATGCTGATCGCGCGCGATGCTAGCTGCTCCGCGCGCGAAT",
"TGAATAGAATTATATAGAATGACGCGCGATGAATCCGCTACGCGATAAGTCCGTAA",
"ACCGCGCTATATAGCGTAAGCTGAATCGCCGCGCGTAAGCTGAATCGCTAGGGGCCGCC",
"TGGTATATACGCGCGCGCCCGCGAATGCTGATCGCCTCGCGCGTAAGATGC",
"CCGTGAATGCCTCGTATATACGCGCTGAATGCCTGCCGCGCGCGCGCGCGCG"]

slicing_list = [9, 16, 13, 9, 20]
```

I want string at position 0 at my_list to slice from the provided integer at position 0 at slicing_list, and ect.

Comment: can show the output you want.

Comment: Your question is missing detail: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the size of each slice so I assume its from the given index to the end of the list:

```
slices = []
for i in range(len(slicing_list)):
    slices.append(my_list[i][slicing_list[i]:])
```

or w/o using an index (the lists should be the same length):

```
slices = []
for sq, ind in zip(my_list, slicing_list):
    slices.append(sq[ind:])
```

And, with list comprehension it should be a bit faster:

```
slices = [sq[ind:] for sq, ind in zip(my_list, slicing_list)]
```

Comment: Thanks! your interperation was correct. any way of doing it with defining a new function and without loops and append?

Comment: @abc_123 I don't see how you can do it w/o a loop. It should run very fast though so I don't think you need it. I added a list comprehension version that should be even faster

Comment: @SiP Whilst a list comprehension *may* be faster in this case (I haven't timed it) that is not a general rule. Explicit nested loops are clearer to understand/maintain and are often faster than complex comprehensions.

Comment: @SiP time is not my problem, it's my assignment to do it without loop..

Comment: @abc_123 then I think you're going to have to use numpy or something that can vectorize the problem

Answer (score 0):

The built-in map function in conjunction with a custom lambda will help with this:

```
my_list = ["GGCTATATAGCGCGATGCTGATCGCGCGCGATGCTAGCTGCTCCGCGCGCGAAT",
"TGAATAGAATTATATAGAATGACGCGCGATGAATCCGCTACGCGATAAGTCCGTAA",
"ACCGCGCTATATAGCGTAAGCTGAATCGCCGCGCGTAAGCTGAATCGCTAGGGGCCGCC",
"TGGTATATACGCGCGCGCCCGCGAATGCTGATCGCCTCGCGCGTAAGATGC",
"CCGTGAATGCCTCGTATATACGCGCTGAATGCCTGCCGCGCGCGCGCGCGCG"]

slicing_list = [9, 16, 13, 9, 20]

print('\n'.join(map(lambda a, b: a[b:], my_list, slicing_list)))
```

**Output:**

```
GCGCGATGCTGATCGCGCGCGATGCTAGCTGCTCCGCGCGCGAAT
GAATGACGCGCGATGAATCCGCTACGCGATAAGTCCGTAA
GCGTAAGCTGAATCGCCGCGCGTAAGCTGAATCGCTAGGGGCCGCC
CGCGCGCGCCCGCGAATGCTGATCGCCTCGCGCGTAAGATGC
CGCGCTGAATGCCTGCCGCGCGCGCGCGCGCG
```

Comment: Thanks! I was actually looking for the sting from the position in the list to the end. any way to do it with defining a new function and without loops?